# Валидация поля с датой

Tags: yii

Пытаюсь сделать такую проверку:

```
    array('e_date_start,e_date_repair_start', 'date' , 'format'=>'dd.MM.yyyy H:i:s'),
```

> 02.03.2015 00:00:00
> Неправильный формат поля дата постановки на учёт.

Comment: У вас вопрос в форме утверждения. Что требуется-то, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем формат надо 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:ii:ss'